# How to loop through each row within a table in a Protractor test?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to write a Protractor test that prints the text within the 4th `<td>` of each row in a table.

Currently, I'm able to print the text contained in the first row using this code:

```
element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then((text) => {
    console.log('Text', text);
});
```

I created the below function to try loop through each row within the table:

```
function checkPrices() {
    element.all(by.tagName("tr")).each((item) => {
        item.element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then((text) => {
            console.log('Text', text);
        });
    });
}
```

But when I run this, I receive this error message:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, td:nth-child(4))

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong & how I can write this loop correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe some row doesn't contain 4 tds, that is why error is thrown. why won't you just get all emenents and get their text.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText()).toEqual(['text1', 'text2', 'text3'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is working, but would this be considered best practice hard-coding an array like that? I'm not saying that it isn't, I'm just asking as I'm new to protractor

Comment: it is a test. It should be simple. if tests are as complex as the app, then why do you write these tests? It seems to me that supporting complex tests just makes the whole work more complex and less reliable

Comment: True, that makes sense! Thanks a lot for your help!